# How to create a mock POST request to test if page has changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have an App.js file that contains a form that when on submitted, causes triggers a state change to render a new page. I'm trying to create a mock Jest test that does these steps:

1. Take mock data
2. Sends a POST request like addInfo is doing
3. Checks if "DONE WITH FORM" is rendered onto the screen.

I also had an idea that we could just fill out a form that takes in the valid_address and valid_number and click a button that triggers the addInfo function to run with the information passed in however I'm unsure of that method and it leads me to a CORS error.

From what I've seen on the web, I think mocking this addInfo using Jest and then testing what is rendered is the best way to go however I'm completely stuck on building this test.

Here's what I have for my App.js

```
const addInfo = async (formInfo) => {
    try {
      let data = {
        valid_number: formInfo.validNumber,
         valid_address: formInfo.validAddress
      }

      let addUserUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_URL +'/verify'
      let addUserData = await fetch(
        addUserUrl,
        { 
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            "x-api-key": process.env.REACT_APP_KEY
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }
      )
      if (addUserData.status !== 200) {
        throw 'Error adding User'
      }

      let addUserDataJson = addUserData.json()

      let ret = {
        added: true,
      }
      return ret
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error')
      let ret = {
        added: false,
      }
      return ret
    }
  }


  const onFinish = async (values: any) => {
      console.log('Transaction verified');
      let addStatus = await addInfo({
        validNumber: "123434",
        validAddress: "D74DS8JDSF",
      })

      if (promoStatus.added) {
        setState({
          ...state,
          showPage: false
        })
      } else {
        setState({
          ...state,
          showPage: true
        })
      }
   };

return (
 {!state.showPage &&
          <>
           <div>
                  <p>
                   DONE WITH FORM
                  </p>
            <div>
          </>
        }
)
```

Here's what I've tried in App.test.js:

```
it('DONE WITH FORM APPEARS', async() =>{

  
            
            // Render App 
          const { getByPlaceholderText, queryByText, getByText } = render(<App />);
            // Entering Valid Number 
           const validNumberInputBox = getByText('Enter Valid Number);
           fireEvent.change(validNumberInputBox, { target: { value: "123434" } });
           expect(validNumberInputBox).toHaveValue("123434");

           // Entering Valid Address
           const validAddressInputBox = getByText('Enter Valid Address');
           fireEvent.change(validAddressInputBox, { target: { value: "D74DS8JDSF" } });
           expect(validAddressInputBox).toHaveValue("D74DS8JDSF");
           
           

           // Button Click
           userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: /Submit/i}));
         
          //Check if the DONE WITH FORM is shown 
          expect(await waitFor(() => getByText('DONE WITH FORM'))).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
```

I've tried almost everything I could find through other stack overflow posts and web articles. so I'd really appreciate any help on how to implement this unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be to mock the async function performing the POST request (addInfo). You never want to try real HTTP requests in unit tests (this won't work since Jest runs in a Node environment where fetch or XMLHttpRequest APIs are not implemented). Beside this, component/unit tests should be independent from any other system like a backend exposing APIs.

To do so, your async function should be in a separate file (so a JS module), then you could mock this module using Jest :

```
// api.js
export const addInfo = () => {...}

// App.test.js
import * as Api from 'api.js';

// here you can define what your mock will return for this test suite
const addInfoSpy = jest.spyOn(Api, 'addInfo').mockResolvedValue({ ret: true });

describe('...', () => {
  test('...', async () => {
    // perform user interactions that should trigger an API call
    expect(addInfoSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('expected addInfos parameter');
    // now you can test that your component displays "DONE WITH FORM" or whatever
    // UI it should be displaying after a successful form submission
  });
});
```

- https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue
- https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname
- https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation! I had no idea I shouldn't be testing POST requests. Why is it I see many people mock GET requests in other stack overflow posts/ web articles?

Comment: In component tests you should mock all HTTP requests (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE...). So I find very convenient to maintain JS modules where you define async functions, matching your backend API, so you can always mock only what you need in component tests. These tests should be completed with integration or end-to-end tests, with a real backend and real REST (or GraphQL) services. In the web world this can be done using Cypress, Nightwatch, Selenium or other E2E web testing frameworks.